# is it possible to validate parameters set to a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

for the below posted code, later, i want to export that code as a function and create a context object for example and then use `provide/inject API` to pass the context object as follows `provide('USER', ctx)`
it is similar to what is shown in the 3rd code snippt in [this link](https://logaretm.com/blog/making-the-most-out-of-vuejs-injections/)

the contents of the context object i would pass to `provide API` is as follows

```
const ctx = {
    evtEmitterParamsCompProperties
}

provide('USER', ctx);
```

my question is, i want to make sure that any value to be passed or assigned to `evtEmitterParamsCompProperties` contains four values and they must be comma separated. to achive that i did the following as shown in the code below:

```
const props = defineProps({
  evtEmitterParamsCompProperties:{
    validator(value) {
      return value.split(',').length == 4
    }
  }
})
```

but `evtEmitterParamsCompProperties` is a computed property. how can i validate the paramters set to `evtEmitterParamsCompProperties` to make sure that what is to be passed to it is of four values and they are comma-sparated.

**code**:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="originDestLonLat('30.976639,30.056021,30.97775,30.033333')">routTest</button>
    result:{{ res }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineProps,defineEmits, ref,computed } from 'vue';
export default {
  name: 'GISWSCaller',
}
const res = ref(null)
let params = null
</script>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  evtEmitterParamsCompProperties:{
    validator(value) {
      return value.split(',').length == 4
    }
  }
})
const emit = defineEmits({
  evtRunWSRouteTest:async (params) => {
    const splitted = params.split(',')
    if (splitted.length == 4) {
      const response = await fetch('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/30.976639,30.056021,30.97775,30.033333')
      res.value =  await response.json()
      return res.value
    }
    return false
  }
})

let evtEmitterParamsCompProperties = computed({
  get() {
    return params
  },
  set(newValue) {
    emit('evtRunWSRouteTest',newValue)
  }
})

// functions
function originDestLonLat(param) {
    console.log("params:",param);
    params = param
    evtEmitterParamsCompProperties.value = param
}
</script>
```